# Drawing a shape inside a UIImageView IOS

Tags: ios, xcode

I am drawing a circle using this code:

```
CGContextRef contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(contextRef, 2.0);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(contextRef, [color CGColor]);
CGRect circlePoint = (CGRectMake(coordsFinal.x, coordsFinal.y, 50.0, 50.0));

CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(contextRef, circlePoint);
```

The circle is added on my UIWindow, but I want it to be added in a UIImageView, maintaining the same coordinates as the UIWindow, so if the coordinates are outside the size of the UIImageView, the circle won't be seen.  dimply draw the circle instead on the view, in the UIImageView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually get an image from your canvas (context) and set that image on your imageview.

```
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```